# Using git to deploy to staging and production versions to different locations

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, bitbucket

I currently develop on my local PC and use git to commit to BitBucket a few times a day solely for versioning and backup.

Now I want to be able to commit directly to the server on which the website is hosted instead, e.g. I want to be able to commit the master files to production and the development branch to the staging server. Is this possible at all and is this the best way to do it? Or should it only ever commit to staging and then somehow go from staging to production?

Any guidance in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to push to staging only, create tags there and `git pull` from production with respective tags.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly commit your changes to the server, but you can pull your changes. either the brute force approach by running a cron job with git pull every few minutes. or with a more sophisticated approach - using a post commit hook. for a full description see http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/automatically-updating-your-website-using-githubs-service-hooks/